# How to override default font alias precedence

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

For cursive fonts I have both the URW Z003 and Écolier Court fonts installed.  I want to use Écolier Court, but `fc-match cursive` shows that Z0003 is being chosen.  I can't remove the Z003 font package because it's a dependency of a number of software packages I want to keep.  I've tried making a fontconfig conf file to change what's chosen but haven't had any luck.

The relevant fontconfig lines for URW Z003, in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-z003.conf`, are:

```xml
  <alias>
    <family>cursive</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Z003</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>

  <alias>
    <family>Z003</family>
    <default>
      <family>cursive</family>
    </default>
  </alias>
```

The relevant fontconfig lines for Écolier Court, in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/61-ecolier-court.conf`, are

```xml
  <alias>
    <family>cursive</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Écolier court</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>

  <alias>
    <family>Écolier court</family>
    <default>
      <family>cursive</family>
    </default>
  </alias>
```

The fontconfig file I've written is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>cursive</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>Écolier court</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>Écolier court</family>
    <prefer>
      <family>cursive</family>
    </prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

I've prefixed my fontconfig file name with both `00-` and `99-`, but in either case `fc-match` shows that fontconfig is always choosing Z003 when asked for a cursive font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, you have misconfigured one rule, you used

```
<prefer>
  <family>cursive</family>
</prefer>
```

Whereas, you should use

```
<default>
  <family>cursive</family>
</default>
```

**Second**, you might also have used a wrong family name. Generally, font names don't come with accents. Check the correct family name with

```
≻ fc-scan ecolier-court.ttf
        family: "Ecolier_court"(s)
        lang: aa|bi|fj|gv|ho|ia|id|ie|io|nr|om|so|sq|ss|st|sw|ts|uz|vo|xh|yap|zu|jv|kj|kwm|ms|ng|rn|rw|sg|sn|su|za(s)
```

If the family name there turned to be **Ecolier_court**, then you have to use that in your configuration.

**Third**, note that the version I downloaded from the net doesn't have the `en` language, which means if your `$LANG` is set to `en` `fc-match cursive` would never match this font. You can explicitly match fonts for a different language using `fc-match cursive:lang=fr` or `env LANG=fr fc-match cursive` e.g. depending on your shell.

There could be other reasons, but let's see whether these three would solve your issue first.

Comment: I tried all three of your suggestions simultaneously, but it made no difference.  And the font file does indeed 1) list the family name as "Ecolier_court", and 2) not include `en` as a language.

Comment: And you want to use it for the English language or another language? If for English, why not just download a version which has English support? The reason it doesn't cover English is missing important English characters

Comment: The version [here](https://www.ffonts.net/Ecolier_court.font.download) supports English e.g.

Comment: It's better if you comment whether you tried the proposed solutions and whether you still have an issue. Ignoring the question asked won't serve the poster nor the community.

Comment: Sorry, I was taking a break from computer stuff.  I tried that font but it didn't help.  I changed the fontconfig conf file to use the new family name "Ecolier", I tried making that particular conf file go first or last, and tried regenerating the fontconfig cache files, all to no avil.

Comment: @MatthewCline: Did you remove your old buggy Ecolier font? You can verify from my paste [here](https://zerobin.net/?a74765d7651d4586#uENDgNIZftkEvI7dyWDJUiqH/gN0672KYeAKR1Yc4dY=) that it worked for me though I also have the Z003 font. Please, paste the full output of the same commands I tried so I can check this for you.

Comment: Removing the buggy font fixed it, thanks!